# What is the best way to draw an arbitrary number of lines in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, multido

I wish to produce a number of sections, each followed by a number of lines i. This is how I have done it using multido to repeat a custom command \drawline i times.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand{\drawline}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \draw [gray] (0,0) -- (\textwidth, 0);%
            \node [above right] at (0,0) {\i.};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \\%
}


\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}    
\multido{\i=1+1}{5}{\drawline}


\section*{Section 2}
\multido{\i=1+1}{4}{\drawline}
    
\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

The problem I am having seems to be related to the breakline `\\` following the tikzpicture definition. I need to break lines between calls of \drawline so that the lines show up in sequence and not next to each other. However, I have two issues:

1. I get an extra unnecessary empty line after the last call of \drawline, meaning extra space between sections.
2. When the lines of one section fill a page more or less perfectly, the next section appears on the following page, but not at the top of the page. There is whitespace between the top of the page and the section title.

The syntax for multido is this according to the documentation:

```
\multido{*variables*}{*repetitions*}{*stuff*}
```

Is there a way to reference *repetitions* as a variable? For instance, if one wanted the line break to apply for all n where n < *repetitions*? In that case, a conditional could be used to break line in all cases but the last one.

Or, can one instead use coordinates in tikzpicture relative to another tikzpicture? This way \drawline could be defined without recourse to the `\\` at the end.

Comment: use `\par` not `\\ `

Comment: Thank you David, that worked. I also had to add \noindent before the tikzpicture, however, because otherwise starting at line 2 all the lines were indented with respect to the first one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not necessary to use `multido` when `tikz` is loaded. Just use `\foreach`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\linespace}{6mm}
\newcommand{\drawlines}[1]{\tikz{\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}
    {\draw[gray](0,-\n*\linespace)node[above right,black]{\n.}--(\textwidth,-\n*\linespace);}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}    
\drawlines{5}

\section*{Section 2}
\drawlines{4}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A fairly general method for repeating things a given number of times, using also the corresponding index.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\REPEAT}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of lines to print, #2 = what to repeat
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\drawline}[1]{%
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{#1.}%
  \leaders\hrule height -2pt depth 2.2pt \hfill
  \hspace*{0pt}\par
}
\newcommand{\drawlines}[1]{\REPEAT{#1}{\drawline{##1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\drawlines{5}

\section{Title}

\drawlines{4}

\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\REPEAT` is the number of repetitions; the second argument is code to execute, where we can refer to the index by `##1`.

In the particular case you want to `\REPEAT` the `\drawline` macro, which sets the current index in a zero width box protruding to the right and then draws a rule the full text width, 2pt below the baseline and with a 0.2pt thickness.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to use Ti*k*Z for this, you could also use LaTeX's built in `\rule`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\drawline[1]
  {\expandafter\drawline@\expandafter1\expandafter;\the\numexpr#1;}
\def\drawline@#1;#2;%
  {%
    \ifnum#1>#2
      \expandafter\@gobbletwo
    \fi
    \@firstofone
      {%
        \drawline@output{#1}%
        \expandafter\drawline@\the\numexpr#1+1;#2;%
      }%
  }
\newcommand\drawline@output[1]
  {%
    \par
    \noindent\rlap{#1.}%
    \textcolor{gray}{\rule[-0.3333em]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}%
    \par
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{Section 1}    
\drawline{5}

\section*{Section 2}
\drawline{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A LaTeX3 version using `\rule` (based on Skillmon's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_dl_line_count
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawlines}{ m }{
    \int_set:Nn \g_dl_line_count {1}
    \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {%
        \par
        \noindent\rlap{\int_use:N \g_dl_line_count.}%
        \textcolor{gray}{\rule[-0.3333em]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}%
        \par
        \int_incr:N \g_dl_line_count
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section*{Section 1}    
\drawlines{5}

\section*{Section 2}
\drawlines{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `\prg_replicate:nn` instead of `\int_step_inline:nn` or `\int_step_function:nN`?

Comment: @Skillmon Simply because I wasn't aware of them. I'm still learning ;)